# How to add audio to Android onclick with multiple sounds on a list view

Tags: java, android, audio, onclick

Ok, I have an app here that I am working on. What I want to do is basically play the sound that the car makes when someone clicks on the particular car. I have looked up on here and google but they all deal with a single button and I have an array of them which makes it hard for me to decide which way to go.i got one sound to work, but its the same sound for every car. How can I get it to pick the particular sound for a particular car click?  My java code is:

```
    package com.example.listviewadapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

        //variables declaration
        ArrayList<Car> arrayCars;
        ListView listViewCars;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            arrayCars=new ArrayList<Car>();


            Car bmw=new Car(R.drawable.bmw,"BMW 330ci", "Silver", 13588);
            Car audi=new Car(R.drawable.audi, "Audi A4", "Gray", 18000);
            Car opel=new Car(R.drawable.opel, "Opel Insigna", "Black", 14000);
            Car mercedes=new Car(R.drawable.mercedes, "Mercedes CLS 320","Black", 16000);
            Car ferrari=new Car(R.drawable.ferrari_enzo, "Ferrari Enzo","White", 93000);
            Car fiesta=new Car(R.drawable.ford_fiesta, "Ford Fiesta","Green", 18000);
            Car porshe=new Car(R.drawable.porshe_cayenne,"Porsche Cayenne","Dark Gray", 101000);
            Car lambo=new Car(R.drawable.lamborghini_gallardo, "Lamborghini Gallardo","orange", 100000);
            Car hyundai=new Car(R.drawable.hyundai_i30, "Hyundai i30","blue", 20000);
            Car honda=new Car(R.drawable.honda_accord, "Honda accord","red", 19000);    

            arrayCars.add(bmw);
            arrayCars.add(audi);
            arrayCars.add(opel);
            arrayCars.add(mercedes);
            arrayCars.add(ferrari);
            arrayCars.add(fiesta);
            arrayCars.add(porshe);
            arrayCars.add(lambo);
            arrayCars.add(hyundai);
            arrayCars.add(honda);




            listViewCars = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_cars);
            ListCarsAdapter adapter = new ListCarsAdapter(this, arrayCars);
            listViewCars.setAdapter(adapter);
            listViewCars.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Car selectedCar = arrayCars.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(this,"You've selected " + selectedCar.getModel()+
                    " "+selectedCar.getColor()
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    MediaPlayer  mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);
    mPlayer .start();;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Media Playback android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).
You can put the MP3 files in your `res/raw` folder and store the identifier in each object:

```
public class Car {
    private int audioID;

    public int getAudioID() {
        return audioID;
    }
}
```

And just play it with the `MediaPlayer`:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Car selectedCar = arrayCars.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(this,"You've selected " + selectedCar.getModel()+
            " "+selectedCar.getColor()
            ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, car.getAudioID());
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: So basically tag an id number on the end of each car object. But how does the program know what sound to play after it gets the audio id? It appears that nothing refers to where I have the audio files stored.

Comment: because I understood that you have one sound for each `car`, so when you instantiate each `car` you tell it which audio is the one you want `ej. Car audi=new Car(R.drawable.audi, "Audi A4", "Gray", 18000, R.raw.audi);` and these audios are stored in `res/raw`